# How do I get the keyboard right under a UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift

My app has two views, one in the top half of the screen, one in the bottom half of the screen. The top half view is called mainView, and the bottom half is called tableView. I have a UITextField in the mainView at the bottom of the mainView. So, I am getting the difference between the tableView's height and the keyboard so I can move the mainView up/down enough so that the keyboard will be directly below the uitextfield. The code I am using below works on iphone 4s and iphone 5, but anything bigger leaves a little bit of whitespace between the textfield and the keyboard. How can I fix this?

```
 func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification) {
        let info  = notification.userInfo!
        let value: AnyObject = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!

        let rawFrame = value.CGRectValue
        let keyboardFrameHeight = view.convertRect(rawFrame, fromView: nil).height
        let bottomSpace = tableView.bounds.height

        let spaceDifference = (keyboardFrameHeight - bottomSpace)

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.mainViewProportionalHeight.constant -= spaceDifference
        animLayout(0.5)
    }
```

To reiterate:

mainView = top half of the view

tableView = bottom half of the view

There is a UITextField attached to the bottom of the mainView, so that the bottom of the mainview = bottom of the mainView. Basically, i am trying to align the mainView right above the keyboard without any whitespace in between.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, is the `keyboardFrameHeight` or `bottomSpace` in any way fractional?

Comment: What is the constraint mainViewProportionalHeight?? And how does the white space look like?

Comment: Neither is fractional. The mainViewProportionalHeight is the proportional hieght of the main view (if that wasn't clear enough :P) The constant moves it up/down by however many points you set it to. The "white space" (sorry, unclear) is the space between the keyboard and the bottom of the main view (the textfield). There should be 0 space between the keyboard and the bottom of the main view. Thanks for commenting! I can't figure this out for the life of me :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found to solve your problem is with the CocoaPod, IQKeyboardManager.

You just have to add it to your podfile and then run pod install and it takes care of positioning your keyboard right below whatever text field your writing in. (Even ones that the keyboard would normally cover)

Here's a link to it: https://cocoapods.org/?q=iqkeyboardmanager

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! The whitespace between the keyboard and the uitextfield doesn't bother me too much; I've already achieved what i wanted, which is preventing the keyboard from covering the textfield. However, I'm curious as to the solution to my bug for academic reasons. Thanks for suggesting a cool solution, though! I'm sure it'll help someone who sees this :)

Comment: Oh, that's fair, I was wondering if that was the case.  If you end up needing to solve this problem again, I'd highly recommend the IQKeyboardManager.  It's really saved me a lot of hassle.

Comment: I've heard great things about cocoapod libraries, and I'll be sure to look into it after mastering the basics.

Comment: @acahreonn I would make sure to include cocoapods in the basics (personally) because I see a lot of newer developers shy away from them.  It's an essential skill for sure.  That said, I really appreciate your learning spirit!